# Who goes next after a double auction card with no auction?

Tags: modern-art

Let's say that I've bought 2 Nex and another player has bought 1 Nex. On my turn, I reveal a "double auction" card from Nex, but I don't add the second card.

Everyone passes, because the second card would instantly end the round in my favour with Nex in the lead. As a result, I get my Nex for free. Is it now:

1. My turn (because "players who have not added a card effectively lose a turn")?
2. The next player's turn?

I only have access to the translated rules, so I'm not sure if losing a turn is only when somebody actually adds a card. 1 would be insanely strong as it would then allow me to play the final Nex, ending the round while having gained an extra painting for free (but that doesn't mean it's not a quirk of the rules). I'd houserule to 2 regardless, but what do the rules actually say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From checking the rules in front of me the next player clockwise would be next auctioneer.

In the 'running and auction rules' it states :-

> When an auction ends, the player who made the highest bid pays the
>   auctioneer the amount of the bid.  If the auctioneer made the highest
>   bid the money is paid to the bank instead. If you win an auction, take
>   the painting and place it face up in front of you. (...) The player to
>   the left of the last auctioned now offers a painting card from his
>   hand for sale.

In the double auction rules it states :-

> If it goes back around to you, with no player offering a second
>   painting, then you get the double painting for free.

Whilst the word 'won' isn't in the rules that player did win the auction and paid nothing to the back and place it in front of them so the next player clockwise becomes auctioneer.

Also I think the idea that the player who played a double auction card had had nothing goes again is unlikely.  This kind of exception to a rule is likely to be explicitly clarified so it feels even more likely that play would just go clock wise as in all other parts the auction rounds.